# Angular5 how to open a sidenav with component loaded on fly inside

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, angular5, angular-services

i have created this on stackbliz 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z85mgj

i wuold like to know how to load on fly component inside sidenav, i mean :
from  **NavigatoComponent** i want to open the sidenav on click with the component **Acomponent**  loaded (declared in **NavigatorModule**) , instead from page1 i want to open the sidenav with **Bcomponent** loaded (declared in **Page1Module**) , and from subpage1 the sidenav will open with **Ccomponent** (declared in **Page1Module**).
I would like avoid a ngswitch case inside sidenav component based on value passed trough events of **sidenavService**. So i thought to create the component on fly or pass the component's reference throug the service.
It's possible do that ? is a good practice or there are other betters way ?

Futhermore do you think routing modules  are setup corretly? 
and also, there is a better way for open/close the sidenav from components imported inside differents modules without using a Rxjs **Subject** in the service ?

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few questions that you asked. Here is a solution if you keen on dynamically loading components to `SideNav` content.

**sidenav.service.ts**

```
import {
  Injectable,
  Component,
  ComponentRef,
  NgModule,
  NgModuleRef,
  Injector,
  Compiler,
  ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';

import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SidenavService {
  public subject = new Subject<string>();

  private sidenavVCRef: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private compiler: Compiler, private injector: Injector,
              private ngModuleRef: NgModuleRef<any>) {}

  // getSidenavVCRef() { return this.sidenavVCRef; }

  setSidenavVCRef(vc: ViewContainerRef) { this.sidenavVCRef = vc; }

  publish(eventName: string, componentName?: string) {
    console.log("qua", this.subject, eventName);
    if (componentName) {
      this.loadComponent(componentName).then(() => {
        this.subject.next(eventName);
      });
    } else {
      this.subject.next(eventName);
    }
  }

  // Create component on the fly, and insert to the view container
  private loadComponent(name: string): Promise<boolean> {

    // create component and module on the fly
    const template = `<span>I am ${name}</span>`;
    const tmpComp = Component({template : template})(class {});
    const tmpModule = NgModule({declarations : [ tmpComp ]})(class {});

    // compile the created module and component,
    // and get a hold of it with a componentRef
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
          .then(factories => {
            // Compiler will return all factories for corresponding components
            // to be created
            // Just take the first one as it is the only one.
            const f = factories.componentFactories[0];

            // create (component) view from its factory and return componentRef
            const compRef = f.create(this.injector, [], null, this.ngModuleRef);

            // just detach all previous views from view container
            this.sidenavVCRef.detach();
            // insert it to its view container
            this.sidenavVCRef.insert(compRef.hostView);

            resolve(true);
          })
          .catch(error => { console.log(error); });
    });
  }
}
```

**navigator.component.ts**

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef,
  AfterViewInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {SidenavService} from '../sidenav.service';
@Component({
  selector : 'app-navigator',
  templateUrl : './navigator.component.html',
  styleUrls : [ './navigator.component.css' ]
})
export class NavigatorComponent implements OnInit,
    AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav;

  @ViewChild('vcDynamicComp', {read : ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService, ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sidenavService.subject.subscribe((value) => {
      console.log("value:", value);
      switch (value) {
      case 'open':
        this.openSidenav();
        break;
      case 'close':
        this.closeSidenav();
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // set sidenav view container reference at as the first thing when view is
    // available
    this.sidenavService.setSidenavVCRef(this.vc);
  }

  private openSidenav() { this.sidenav.toggle(); }

  private closeSidenav() { this.sidenav.close(); }

  openSN() { this.sidenavService.publish('open', 'Component A'); }
}
```

**navigator.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="false">
        Sidenav content
        <div #vcDynamicComp></div>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <mat-toolbar>My App
            <span style=" flex: 1 1 auto"></span>
            <button mat-raised-button routerLink="/page1">Page1</button>
            <button mat-raised-button routerLink="/page2">Page2</button>
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openSN()">Open sidenav</button>
        </mat-toolbar>
        <main>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </main>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Here is the [working example at stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sg-dynamic-sidenav)

Comment: Thank you! anyway there is a way to avoid create component on fly?
my component inside sidenav could be very  complex, i prefer not create it inside sidenavService, can i import it ?

Comment: This is just a simplified implementation. You can create a separate `service` for your dynamic component and inject it in any components/directives/other services as you need in a proper way.